# ROS Answers SE migration: Enum in msg

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

does anybody know if there's a way to put an *enum* type into a message? How's it done?

Thanks!

Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9427/enum-in-msg/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use constants in ROS messages:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg#Constants

They don't map explicitly to higher-level enum types in programming languages, but they generally let you deal with the same issues.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-15**:
@Murph: that's correct

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-15**:
Do you mean something like .. create an integer field, then create a series of constant fields to map integer values to the enumerated types?

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-04-27**:
I know this is a very old chain, however has this been implemented? Could I have a look?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example from joystick_drivers https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers :

```
$ rosmsg show sensor_msgs/JoyFeedbackArray 
sensor_msgs/JoyFeedback[] array
uint8 TYPE_LED=0
uint8 TYPE_RUMBLE=1
uint8 TYPE_BUZZER=2
uint8 type
uint8 id
float32 intensity
```

There is nothing special or required about the constants TYPE_LED and TYPE_RUMBLE being capitalized or having a prefix in common with the field 'type' for which they are supposed to be the values it ought to have.

In https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/blob/groovy-devel/ps3joy/scripts/ps3joy_node.py the usage of the enum like fields is shown for Python:

```
rospy.Subscriber("joy/set_feedback",sensor_msgs.msg.JoyFeedbackArray,self.set_feedback)
...
def set_feedback(self,msg):
  for feedback in msg.array:
    if feedback.type == sensor_msgs.msg.JoyFeedback.TYPE_LED and feedback.id < 4:
      self.led_values[feedback.id] = int(round(feedback.intensity))
    elif feedback.type == sensor_msgs.msg.JoyFeedback.TYPE_RUMBLE and feedback.id < 2:
...
```

In C++ it would look like this:

```
if (msg->waveform == sensor_msgs::JoyFeedback::TYPE_RUMBLE)
...
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2013-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19